# Backing up Attachments Object

Tags: data-export

Hi I recently checked Salesforce export backups and realize that I wasn't backing up the attachment object. What's a good free tool I can use to do this?

Comment: why not check the box at the top of `Setup | Data management | Data Export` to include attachments in the backup?

Comment: I would have done this but attachments isn't an option

Comment: are you using https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_exportdata.htm&language=en_US ? -there is a checkbox at the top of the wizard to include attachments.